# Solr Boosting on custom fields

Tags: solr, search-engine

Solr Experts,

I am trying to change the score for few of my custom fields through index time/field boosting but doesn't seems to be changing the score. Please help.

These are my custom fields in schema.xml

```
 <field name="doc_id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="false"/>
 <field name="doc_name" type="text_autocomplete" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" omitNorms="false"/>
 <field name="doc_author" type="text_autocomplete" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
 <field name="modifieddate" type="text_autocomplete" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
 <field name="doc_content" type="text_autocomplete" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" omitNorms="false"/>
 <field name="doc_title" type="text_autocomplete" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
 <field name="doc_description" type="text_autocomplete" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" omitNorms="false"/>
```

I posted 3 test docs as below using SolrJ

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<add>
  <doc>
   <field name="doc_id">7781</field>
   <field name="doc_name" boost="1.5">Cat</field>
   <field name="doc_author">Nsd80</field>
   <field name="modifieddate">11 30</field>
   <field name="doc_content" boost="1.5">Cat life history. Cat life cycle. Cat Foods</field>
   <field name="doc_title">Titled</field>
   <field name="doc_description" boost="1.5">Cat related details</field>
  </doc>
  <doc>
     <field name="doc_id">7782</field>
     <field name="doc_name" boost="2.5">Dog</field>
     <field name="doc_author">Nsd80</field>
     <field name="modifieddate">11 30</field>
     <field name="doc_content" boost="2.5">Dog life history. Dog life cycle. Dog Foods</field>
     <field name="doc_title">Titled</field>
     <field name="doc_description" boost="2.5">Dog details</field>
  </doc>
  <doc>
     <field name="doc_id">7783</field>
     <field name="doc_name" boost="2.7">Cow</field>
     <field name="doc_author">Nsd80</field>
     <field name="modifieddate">11 30</field>
     <field name="doc_content" boost="2.7">Cow life history. Cow life cycle. Cow Foods</field>
     <field name="doc_title">Titled</field>
     <field name="doc_description" boost="2.7">Cow lifecycle</field>
  </doc>
</add>
```

When I query to find the scores as below,

```
localhost:8983/solr/select/?q=doc_id:*&fl=*,score
```

it shows 1.0 as score for all three docs

I was trying to boost them as

```
localhost:8983/solr/select?defType=edismax&q=doc_description:*Cow*^195
```

but doesnt seems to be working either

```
<arr name="doc_description">
<str>Dog details</str>
</arr>
<long name="_version_">1479948142366425088</long>
<float name="score">1.0</float>
</doc>
<doc>
```

Also tried to elevate as

```
localhost:8983/solr/elevate?q=doc_id:7781&enableElevation=true&fl=doc_id,score,[elevated]
```

but result was negative

```
<result name="response" numFound="1" start="0" maxScore="7.23343">
<doc>
<str name="doc_id">7781</str>
<float name="score">7.23343</float>
<bool name="[elevated]">false</bool>
</doc>
</result>
</response>
```

My requirement is just to boost the docs to have more scores so that I can retrieve them based on scores. If you look at my xml docs, I have tried field boosting at index time, later tried to boost the docs using edismax ([mentioned here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin#bq_.28Boost_Query.29)) and also a [elevation](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/QueryElevationComponent)

Can anyone help me with detailed example?

Comment: Have you tried localhost:8983/solr/select?defType=edismax&q=Cow&qf=doc_description^195

Comment: Agree with @everreadyeddy you need to use qf param for boosting. for more info check this page http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtendedDisMax

Comment: Thank you both. I tried both but doesn't seems working. this query doesn't results in anything and was showing <lst name="params">
<str name="q">Cow</str>
<str name="qf">doc_description^195</str>
<str name="defType">edismax</str>
</lst>
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="0" start="0"/>
</response> I tried this way http://localhost:8983/solr/select?defType=edismax&q=doc_description:*Cow*&qf=doc_description^195 which returns the doc but does not increase the score. :-(